# How to loop through a string that contain multiple td using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Background story, I am working on a chrome extension that would allow people retrieve specific data from the user content page and do some calculation.

The problem I am having is how can I filter through a string that contain multiple td element, to get it's innerText and then store each one found into an array.

**HTML Table content & Javascript:**

```
<table id="countryList">
     <tr>
         <td>Europe</td>
         <td>France</td>
         <td>Sweden</td>
         <td>Germany</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Asia</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>Thailand</td>
         <td>Japan</td>
     </tr>
</table> 

var table = document.getElementById('countryList');
var tdArray = new Array;
for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) 
{
    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
        var stringContainTd = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML);
    }
}

//loop through stringContainTd to find each td element and store it's innerText into tdArray.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which will return list of matched element in an array. Then use `forEach` to loop through this array and use `textContent` to get the text

```js
var arr = [];
var getTDContent = document.querySelectorAll('td');
getTDContent.forEach(function(item) {
  arr.push(item.textContent); // for pushing into arr
})
```

```html
<table id="countryList">
  <tr>
    <td>Europe</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Asia</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>Thailand</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively you can also use array.map method bu the catch is `map` does not work on `nodelist`, but `Array.prototype.map.call` will help in using map method

```js
var arr = [],
  getTDContent = document.querySelectorAll('td');
arr = Array.prototype.map.call(getTDContent, function(item) {
  return item.textContent;
})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<table id="countryList">
  <tr>
    <td>Europe</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Asia</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>Thailand</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```